# SQL query works in access but not in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get data from a recordset. The SQL query works fine in MS Access and returns exactly the expected values, but when the same query is lunched in VBA Excel, I get the following error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Do you have any ideas why this problem occurs?

Thank you.

Philippe-Olivier Roussel

```
Private Sub CBtype_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strConnexion As String
    Dim connexion As New ADODB.Connection
    strConnexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Database & ""
    connexion.Open strConnexion

    Dim rsMarque As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim seltype As String



    seltype = CBtype.Value


    rsMarque.Open "SELECT DISTINCT tblMarque.marque_nom FROM tblMarque, tblModele WHERE " & _
      " tblMarque.marque_id = tblModele.marque_id AND tblModele.marque_id IN " & _
      " (SELECT DISTINCT tblModele.marque_id FROM tblModele, tblType " & _
      " WHERE tblModele.type_id = tblType.type_id AND tblModele.type_id = " & _
       " (SELECT tblType.type_id FROM tblType WHERE " & _
       " (tblType.type_nom = " & seltype & ")))", connexion, adOpenStatic



    rsMarque.MoveFirst
    With UserForm2.CBmarque
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rsMarque!marque_nom
            rsMarque.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsMarque.EOF
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think Excel speaks SQL. Excel is not technically a database. It's a spreadsheet. Access is Excel turned into a database, so it speaks SQL.

Comment: When you working through VBA with recordset object, it works.

Comment: Ok. News to me :)

Comment: `"No value given for one or more required parameters.".` which line is it giving the error?

Comment: The "rsMarque.Open". Also, the variable seltype refer to a txt value in another combobox.

Comment: We haven't found the problem but we found a way to bypass it by using the ListIndex Function. 

The first column of our access table was numbers so we used this program:                                                                                

rsMarque.Open "SELECT DISTINCT tblMarque.marque_nom FROM tblMarque, tblModele WHERE tblMarque.marque_id = tblModele.marque_id AND tblModele.marque_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT tblModele.marque_id FROM tblModele, tblType WHERE tblModele.type_id = tblType.type_id AND tblModele.type_id = (" & CBtype.ListIndex + 1 & "))", connexion, adOpenStatic

Comment: `1` Is the code work exactly like it is in access? `2` Did you try to step through the code? Is expected value being passed in `seltype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message looks like an output from the DBMS rather than Excel

I think you might be missing the apostrophe before and after your string variable. See if

`" (tblType.type_nom = '" & seltype & "')))"` works (I'm assuming the column you're querying is varchar type, since you declared `seltype` as string)